# Smartphone Camera Module as Camera for Raspberry pi

Tags: pi-4, raspicam

I wanted to ask if it was possible to hook the Camera of my old Galaxy J5 2016 (Picture) up with the Raspberry Pi.
The Connector has 17 pins on each side and should be CIS. On the back of the Camera is written "NEW-J5 67424P8HD42203" but i could'nt find any kind of paper about the Camera with this, to maybe find a Pinout.
So basically what i am looking for is some kind of adapter to connect it to the Raspberry.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without a datasheet this is not possible, as in the chance you connect everything correctly is really small.

I found a site where they sell these: https://www.witrigs.com/oem-rear-camera-for-samsung-galaxy-j5-2016, maybe you can ask them if they have a datasheet/pinout.

Comment: Good Idea, i will try that